# Login with pin but display "Welcome $username"

Tags: php, mysql, session, authentication

I have created a basic login page where users login using a 6 digit pin which is verified by data in a table and starts their session using PHP. On login at the welcome page I would like to show "Welcome username", where username is the corresponding name from the table - user_first.

Here's my login :

```
$error='';
if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
    require 'dbconnect_inc.php';
    $loginid = $_POST['loginid'];
    $result = mysqli_query($conn, 'SELECT * FROM hpnhusers WHERE user_loginid="'.$loginid.'"');

    if (mysqli_num_rows($result)==1) {
        $_SESSION['loginid'] = $loginid;
        header ('Location: welcome.php');
    } else {
        $error = 'Invalid PIN';
    }
  }

//Logout script
if (isset($_GET['logout'])) {
session_unregister('loginid');
}
```

My SQL table looks like this:

```
user_id    user_first    user_last    user_loginid
   1          Bob           Jones        123456
```

I'm guessing the correct query to find the corresponding name would be:

```
$username = mysqli_query($conn, 'SELECT user_first FROM hpnhusers WHERE user_loginid="'.$loginid.'"');
```

But unfortunately, I can't get my head around how to put it all together to get it to work.

All and any help greatly appreciated as I'm still learning.

Comment: Get the `user_id` from your login query. Then, use that ID to query whatever information you need from the record.

Comment: btw, does that session array contain value?

Comment: **WARNING**: When using `mysqli` you should be using [parameterized queries](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) and [`bind_param`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php) to add user data to your query. **DO NOT** use string interpolation or concatenation to accomplish this because you have created a severe [SQL injection bug](http://bobby-tables.com/). **NEVER** put `$_POST`, `$_GET` or **any** user data directly into a query, it can be very harmful if someone seeks to exploit your mistake.

Comment: Note: The object-oriented interface to `mysqli` is significantly less verbose, making code easier to read and audit, and is not easily confused with the obsolete `mysql_query` interface. Before you get too invested in the procedural style it’s worth switching over. Example: `$db = new mysqli(…)` and `$db->prepare("…")` The procedural interface is an artifact from the PHP 4 era when `mysqli` API was introduced and should not be used in new code.

Comment: **WARNING**: Writing your own access control layer is not easy and there are many opportunities to get it severely wrong. Please, do not write your own authentication system when any modern [development framework](http://codegeekz.com/best-php-frameworks-for-developers/) like [Laravel](http://laravel.com/) comes with a robust [authentication system](https://laravel.com/docs/master/authentication) built-in. At the absolute least follow [recommended security best practices](http://www.phptherightway.com/#security) and **never store passwords as plain-text** or a weak hash like **SHA1 or MD5**.

Answer (score 1):

First thing, don't just accept user input and use it in a query.

```
$loginId = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'loginid', FILTER_SANITIZE_INTEGER);
```

Now, build a parameterized query, don't use ad-hoq queries when you don't have to

```
$query = $con->prepare("SELECT * FROM hpnhusers WHERE user_loginid = ?");
$query->bind_param("i", $loginId);
$query->execute();

$firstName = $query->fetch_object()->user_first;
```

I don't have access to a machine with PHP installed but I think the above should get the user name for you.

Comment: "Ad-hoc", technically, but great demonstration of both the sanitization functions and how prepared statements aren't hard.

Comment: Sure, but it doesn't answer the question though, IMHO @tadman

Comment: Cheers @crunchy I'll give that a go. Security/SQL Injections/Prepared statements aren't relevant to me at the minute, just a working prototype would suffice to get correct functionality. Pretty picture stuff at the minute if you understand what I mean.